# How do I get Kp?

Tags: pid-controller

[image]

How do you get the equation for Kp? I know where R2/R1 comes from, but no idea about + Cd/Ci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer function \$G_c(s)\$ for this inverting op-amp compensator is:

$$G_c(s)=-\frac{Z_f(s)}{Z_i(s)}$$

The transfer function for a PID compensator is:

$$G_{PID}=\frac{k_D s^2+k_Ps+k_I}{s}$$

Solve for \$G_c(s)\$. Manipulate and compare.

You should be able to take it from here

Answer (score 1):

That is a very bad circuit, at least not for DC. Ci (at DC) has infinite impedance, so no current can flow in the feedback path, and the circuit will saturate.
I'm going to guess that the circuit makes some assumptions you haven't included. I'm guessing you are stuck with this circuit as part of a course, but I don't recommend it. It's much cleaner to use a 4-op-amp circuit with each term independent, so you don't have to worry about the terms interacting as you do with this.

Comment: "and the circuit will saturate" as long as you choose an op-amp that saturates and comes out of saturation cleanly, that's not a bug, and handled correctly, may well be a feature.

Comment: "and the circuit will saturate" , Standalone you are right, but when this is used as a forward path PID compensator within an outer feedback loop. The outer feedback will allow the integrator to not saturate, This is a clever way to get P,I, and D in a single op-amp. It is not designed for ease of adjustment. It reduces parts count significantly. Not a bad circuit if used appropriately. Anyway this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes, this is only one of four circuits we are currently examining. The circuit you mentioned is the 4th one I‘ll have to look at.

Comment: @RussellH With the outer loop feedback, does it also avoid windup problems?

Comment: Windup due to operational amplifier input offset can easily be removed. Still use devices with low offset values.

Comment: @RussellH what about windup due to actuator saturation?

Answer (score -1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXUGSc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=0\space\text{V}\tag4$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-0}{\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathscr{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=-\frac{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V1 = 0;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I0 == I1 + I2, 0 == I1 + I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (Vi - V1)/R2, I3 == (V2 - V1)/R3}, {V2, I0, I1, I2, I3}]]

Out[1]={{V2 -> -(((R1 + R2) R3 Vi)/(R1 R2)), I0 -> (1/R1 + 1/R2) Vi, 
  I1 -> Vi/R1, I2 -> Vi/R2, I3 -> -(((R1 + R2) Vi)/(R1 R2))}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

So, applying this to your case we can see that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{E}\left(\text{s}\right)}\\
\\
&=-\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{i}}\right)\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{d}}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_\text{d}}}\\
\\
&=-\left(\text{C}_\text{d}\text{R}_2\text{s}+\frac{1}{\text{C}_\text{i}\text{R}_1\text{s}}+\frac{\text{C}_\text{d}}{\text{C}_\text{i}}+\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1}\right)\\
\\
&=-\left(\underbrace{\text{C}_\text{d}\text{R}_2}_{=\space\text{K}_\text{d}}\cdot\text{s}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{\text{C}_\text{i}\text{R}_1}}_{=\space\text{K}_\text{i}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}}+\underbrace{\frac{\text{C}_\text{d}}{\text{C}_\text{i}}+\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1}}_{=\space\text{K}_\text{p}}\right)
\end{split}\tag7
\end{equation}

Comment: Can the one who downvoted my answer explain why, so that I can learn from it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did not downvote, but your answer makes no sense in one term. Your last term, which you identify as Kp, includes a term at DC of Cd/Ci. Since at DC there is no current whatever flowing through the capacitors, this term is meaningless. Another way to put is is the your third term in equation 2 must be zero when a capacitor term is added (again, at DC). So R3 becomes infinite. This cascades through the rest of your analysis.

Comment: The current on (2) should be `i(t) = C d(v(t))/dt`, you should get differential equations in time-domain instead. You could also write it in Laplace domain if you like such as `I(s) = C (s V(s) - v(0))`, and with zero initial condition (ZIC), `v(0) = 0V`